# Why flights route is so different?

Tags: airlines, flight-path

Let's take a look to itinerary of a flight from Dubai to Tokyo taken [here](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/ek318)

[image]

And from Tokyo to Dubai
[image]

It's the same airline.

One more example. Here is the route of flight from Istanbul to Tokyo
[image]

And from Tokyo to Istanbul
[image]

Can somebody explain why return route is so different flying from East to West?

Comment: base guess, it has to do with winds aloft.

Comment: Also related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/13428/ and https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29926/

Comment: Also note that the map projection (at least for the last example) makes the difference appear much bigger than it actually is

Comment: As @J.Hougaard mentionned, routes are bent by the map projection. Here a [view from above the Earth](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=RJAA-LTBA&MS=bm&MP=o&MC=45N+060E&DU=mi). On this image this is the shortest path (great circle) which is shown. You can change the type of projection on the page, as well as the center of the map. You may also add intermediary waypoints

Comment: Why is a question about asian flight routes marked as a duplicate of a question on transatlantic flight routes?

Comment: @falstro probably because it's the same reason and we don't need a question for every route possible.

Comment: @Notts90 Interesting, do you have any literature reference to back up the claim that it is, in fact, the same reason? If you so, can you put it down as an answer? :) Seriously though, someone might actually disagree with you,  these particular instances could - for example - be geopolitical reasons and not jetstream. Do these routes actually correspond to the jetstream? I've made the same case over and over, the question is not a duplicate. The answer might be, but are you 100% sure it is? If not, someone else might actually have a better answer.

Comment: @falstro no I'm not 100% but I also didn't VTC or flag the answer as dupe. I'm just suggesting the probable reason why it was closed. If you have evidence to the contrary then post it in chat and get it reopened.

Comment: @Notts90 I see that, I'm just countering that reason for others to see. You just got caught in the crossfire, sorry :)